# Deploying Click once on production environment

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, clickonce

This is strange but I was not able to find a simple guide, supposedly of a trivial task.

I can publish my Click-once application on IIS through visual studio. Now I want to move the application to client side. There I don’t have visual studio.

No how do I change the server of my click once application which is hosted on my system to client system?

I was able to find many guides describing how to do it through visual studio in dev environment, but I was not able to find the guide on how to do it on production without visual studio

Any guide or steps will be very helpful

Comment: Microsoft makes a tool for this. Look up MAGE.exe (command line) or MAGEUI.exe (GUI)

Answer (score 0):

There are in principle two ways how to the create a ClickOnce publication.

1. Using Visual Studio publishing wizard as you do.
2. Using `MAGE.exe` or `MAGEUI.exe` 
   (in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\`). - watch out that you use the right version.

But ClickOnce application **consists of 1 file and 1 folder that can be copied**.

So you just publish internaly to your server, and then just copy the `.application` file and appropriate one folder with latest version which resides under `Application Files` folder. You do not need to setup any extra publishing software, I think.